# Java 8 Nested Streams Filtering

Tags: java

Here are my classes:

```
class File {
  String id;
  String name;
  List<Metadata> metadata;
}

class Metadata {
  String key;
  String value;
}
```

I have a list of files (`List<File>`), I wanted to filter first by the name of the File, and then filter by the matching key and value from the list of `Metadata`.

Let's say, I wanted to return the `id` of the File which name is "movie.mp4" and one of its metadata should have `key=="genre"` and `value=="Horror"`.

Using Java 8 Streams, I can filter by the name of File, but not sure how to go down another level and filter by the matching key and value.

How do I do this?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `stream()` on the `metadata` and test if any `key` and `value` match your criteria. Something like,

```
fileList.stream().filter(f -> f.name.equals("movie.mp4")
        && f.metadata.stream().anyMatch(x -> x.key.equals("genre")
        && x.value.equals("Horror")));
```